# Dictionary to CSV file: 'ValueError: Too many values to unpack'

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I'm trying write the data to the file dict.csv using this code:

```
file = open('dict.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(file)
for key, val in currencies:
    w.writerow([key, val])
    file.close()
```

When I run the above code I get a 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.

How do I write a dictionary to a csv file without getting the ValueError? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python2 use `iteritems`:

```
for key, val in currencies.iteritems():
  w.writerow([key, val])
```

In Python3 just use `items`:

```
for key, val in currencies.items():
  w.writerow([key, val])
```

And remember to put `file.close()` outside the loop:

```
for ....:
  w.writerow([key, val])
file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to access the dictionary in this way, you need to call the method `iteritems`:

```
for key, val in currencies.iteritems():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

As **@tobias_k** pointed out, you should remove `file.close()` from the loop.

As a side note, here is another way to accomplish the same result.

```
for key in currencies:
    w.writerow([key,currencies[key]])
```